# How to refresh a User object cached in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use this `User` class provided by Google App Engine: `from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User`

I want to make some change to an instance of User via Data Store in the Google cloud console: change the `name` attribute of a `User` to something else.

As far as I know the `User` object is cached in some way. If I make the change directly in data store, how can I locate it in the memcache and delete it? My goal is to force the cached `User` object to be refreshed.

Comment: This might be an option https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051668/6017784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memcache key used can be found in google.appengine.ext.context.py: Context.get():

```
if use_memcache:
  mkey = self._memcache_prefix + key.urlsafe()
```

The prefix (in my version at least) is 'NDB9:'. So to get the memcache key you can use something similar to:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

key = ndb.Key('User', 5229916580741120)
mkey = 'NDB9:' + key.urlsafe()
print mkey
```

This results in something like: `NDB9:ahpzfmR5bmFtaWMtdHJhdmVsbGVyLTItdGVzdHIRCxIEVXNlchiAgIDAzZKlCQw`

To delete:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
value = memcache.get(mkey)
result = memcache.delete(mkey)
print "Memcache delete result={}".format(result)
if result == 2:
  print "{} memcache value has been deleted".format(key)
elif result == 1:
  print "{} memcache value not found".format(key)
else:
  print "Failed to delete {} memcache value".format(key)
```

Caveat: without the memcache.get() call before memcache.delete() the delete result was always '1' (not found) using the interactive console. Not sure why that's the case.